# Hide soft keyboard from input method service

Tags: android, android-input-method

I am trying to hide my soft keyboard from an InputMethodService, and it isn't working. Here is the code I am using in my onFinishInput() method:

```
InputMethodManager im = (InputMethodManager)
context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
im.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mInputView.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/how-to-close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard

Comment: The difference is I am calling this from an InputMethodService - not an Activity

Comment: @hsnepen, huh? You are calling hideSoftInputFromWindow ON the InputMethodManager. This call, presumably, is taking place inside of an Activity. Oh, and this is a duplicate for sure: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/how-to-close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard

Comment: I am extending the InputMethodService - not an Activity. This is NOT being called from inside of an Activity. It is being called inside an extension of a Service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide soft keyboard from manifest , Try this one:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

Comment: This would not be the answer to hide the keyboard from an `InputMethodService`. This is what you would do in an Activity.

Comment: Why this answer is selected? Any explanation? Seems unrelated to topic.

Answer (score 6):

The following has worked for me:

```
requestHideSelf(0);

mInputView.closing();
```

Comment: Works great. 
Ignore the mInputView.closing();

requestHideSelf(0); does it alone.

Comment: from https://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/InputMethodService.html#requestHideSelf(int)